# Magento1.9 customer can't reset password

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getBackend() on boolean in
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php:1553

Stack trace:

> 1. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(332): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->saveAttribute(Object(EW_NativePasswords_Model_Customer_Customer),
>      'rp_token_create...')
> 2. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(1390): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken(Object(EW_NativePasswords_Model_Customer_Customer),
>      '2e7628921453636...')
>      3.app/code/local/My/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(113): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken('2e7628921453636...')

Answer (score 0):

Is it one customer or all customers?

Seems like an issue with the extension that has been introduced to handle password hashing.

I'm not sure the impact on disabling.  If you disable you may stop all your customers being able to log in.

https://github.com/ericthehacker/magento-phpnativepasswords

Perhaps there is a new version available?

There is an option to disable.

System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options -> Use PHP Native Password Hashing and set to No.

Again I can't predict the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

It was basically a data issue. I don't know how it happened but somehow the entity_type_id for this attribute was updated.
I reseted it and it worked.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is a issue with the missing Attribute

that is **password_created_at** attribute in the **eav_attribute** table.

while installing the magento the upgrade script is not run properly, due to this
reason password_created_at attribute is not created.

I just downgraded the **customer_setup** version to 1.6.2.0.5  in the **core_resource** table

After created this attribute it is working fine.